# Plus (+) sign in SVN filename

Tags: svn, iis, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server, arr

I am having some issues committing files to my VisualSVN server when the files contain plus (+) signs in the names. This is something I need for iOS development. When I try to commit a file with a name that contains a plus sign I get the following errors:

> svn: E155011: File 'C:...\Foo+Bar.txt' is out of date
>
> svn: E160013: '/svn/Test/!svn/txr/1-8/Foo+Bar.txt' path not found

This is extremely frustrating. I have tried several clients (TortoiseSVN, Apache SVN) on both Windows and Mac OS X, with both 1.6 and 1.7 clients. I'm suspecting this might be a VisualSVN issue, unless plus signs are always special in SVN. If so, is there any workaround (e.g. escaping a plus sign or something). I haven't been able to find anything regarding this on Google.

Comment: Plus sign is a valid sign in filename. 1. What's logged to server log? 2. Did you run `svn up` against the working copy prior to running `svn ci`?

Comment: The server doesn't seem to be logging anything for the errors. Yes, I tested with a clean, new, repository. I created a new file containing a plus sign. Adding the file seems to work fine, however, transferring the file data causes the errors above. The "out of date" error seems very misleading...

Comment: I can't reproduce the error in testing environment.

So, you've tested the behavior with a clean repository (no hooks, no other committers, Read / Write access) and you can commit files without '+' in path but with '+' it fails. Is there any proxy between the client and the VisualSVN Server instance? Please describe the exact actions you perform and what SVN client version you use.

Comment: Yes. I am running IIS Application Request Routing. I can't believe this didn't cross my mind since I have been having other issues with ARR with SVN 1.8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was caused by my IIS Application Request Routing proxy. The solution was to allow "double escaping".

[See this link for more details](http://www.ifinity.com.au/Blog/EntryId/60/404-Error-in-IIS-7-when-using-a-Url-with-a-plus-sign-in-the-path).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone as confused as me, this might allow "double escaping" from matlab if you have the right permissions.

```
system('%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config "Default Web Site" -section:system.webServer/security/requestFiltering -allowDoubleEscaping:true')
```